# ¿ Implementar un BottomBar sin Fragments?

Tags: java, android, bottombar

Me explico, tengo un `BottomBar` implementado con 5 Fragments, pero me da muchísimos problemas, no puedo hacer prácticamente nada , pues cada fragment está extendido como `Fragment` , no como `FragmentActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomBar mBottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int i) {


                if (i == R.id.one) {

                    First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f1).commit();

                }

                if (i == R.id.two) {

                    Second_fragment f2 = new Second_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f2).commit();

                }

                if (i == R.id.three) {

                    Three_fragment f3 = new Three_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f3).commit();

                }

                if (i == R.id.four) {

                    Four_fragment f4 = new Four_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f4).commit();

                }

                if (i == R.id.five) {

                    Five_fragment f5 = new Five_fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f5).commit();

                }    
            }

        });

        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#c92029");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, "#c92029");    
    }
}
```

Pongo por ejemplo `First_Fragment` , los otros 4 son igual:

```
public class First_fragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

El problema está en **extends Fragment** , me da muchísimos problemas. Mis anteriores preguntas fueron de una simple `listView` y una `WebView`pues en Fragment TODO falla. **¿ Alguien sabe cómo cambiar a `FragmentActivity` de alguna forma o no implementar con `Fragments` ?

Comment: El que busca encuentra mi estimado https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar, es una pregunta similar a la anterior, espero no te la cierren.

Comment: He buscado docenas de bottomBar y entre esos, está ese que me has pasado, es mas, lo tengo abierto ahora mismo paralelamente al mío, pero no me sirve... no está implementado ninguna activity. Cuando cambia en ese ejemplo de icono en el bottombar, simplemente muestra un TextView.

Comment: Lo que necesito es saber como implementar tal como tengo yo, pero en FragmentActivity o en Activity, no en Fragment... En ese ejemplo solo ponen TextView y ya está.... :(

Comment: @x4mp73r ese se lo pase yo sino me equivoco en otra pregunta anterior, en cuanto a los problemas que te da, ¿a que te refieres? Yo he realizado `listviews` y `webviews` dentro de fragments y no me han dado muchos problemas que recuerde, Me he puesto a pensar como hacerlo sin fragments y no veo la forma sin hacer que se cambie de Activity o que se pueda hacer de una forma sencilla

Comment: Es mala práctica usar FragmentActivity

Comment: Se lo pregunté a un amigo y me lo dijo, cambiaba algo, minimamente, pero nunca lo habia hecho en Fragment, ya esta solucionado, mas tarde pondre alguna pregunta si no consigo hacer un par de cosas, son pequeñas, tipo poner un icono en algun sitio, pero primero lo intento yo, como siempre, gracias a todos.

Comment: Os doy un +1 a los que habéis participado porque todos ayudáis :D

Comment: @Joacer ¿Y que tiene de malo que se lo vuelva a colocar? .-. no te molestes por algo como eso.

Comment: @x4mp73r no sino me molestó, igual no me di a entender bien, quería decir que ese se lo pase en otra pregunta, por lo que igual ya le habría echado un ojo o habría intentado trabajar con él. Si ha dado esa sensación lo siento